# Edit sql data in php page

Tags: php, sql, select, edit, display

I need to edit my database table using submitted data.

This is the form:

```
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");

$query = "SELECT * FROM sec1octa"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<div align="center">
    <form method="get" action="edit_data.php">
        <table width="104" border="1" class="center1">
            <tr>
                <th width="94">first</th>
                <th width="94">second</th>
                <th width="94">status</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <?php
                if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row ['stu_no']; ?> " size=10></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row ['stu_name']; ?> " size=10></td> 
                            <td><?php 
                                echo '<select name="status">';   {
                                    echo '<option value="open">'.$row['stu_status'].'</option>';
                                    echo '<option value="close">'.prevent.'</option>';
                                }
                                echo '</select>';
                            ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="done" />
    </form>
```

The problem is in the edit_data.php page.
I can't `UPDATE`.

I use this code but it's not working.

```
require_once('../Connections/config.php');
$id= $_GET['id'];
$status= $_GET['status'];

$query=  mysql_query("UPDATE  `goh`.`sec1octa` SET  `stu_status` =  '$status' 
WHERE stu_no='".$id."'") or die (mysql_error ());
if($query){echo $status ."done ";}
```

Comment: You have a typo : $qeury instead of $query. And share the error you have.

Comment: no error appear , it's just make UPDATE in 2 column in my database , the last column ( number 42 ) and column number (40) , and when i try to make update to another column also make update to number 42

Comment: @mickmackusa , how can i clean it , please ? , also how can i use name filed in edit_data.php ? or it's not useful ?

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you very much , done . and i'm wait if someone can help me with this code to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are only getting the last values in your `edit_data.php` `$_GET` is because you are not setting the input/select names as arrays.

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="some_stu_no">
```

is happening over and over and over and every new one overwrites the previous.

Instead, you should use:

```
<input type="text" name="id[]" value="some_stu_no">
```

This will allow you to pass multiple id's in a single form submission.

Your form:

```
<form method="POST" action="edit_data.php">
....
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>id</th>";
    echo "<th>name</th>";
    echo "<th>status</th>";
echo "</tr>";
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"id[]\" value=\"{$row['stu_no']}\" size=\"10\"></td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['stu_name']}</td>"; 
            echo "<td>";
                echo "<select name=\"status[]\">";  // I don't like your option set up here, but I don't fully understand it either.
                    echo "<option value=\"open\">{$row['stu_status']}</option>";
                    echo "<option value=\"close\">.prevent.</option>";
                echo "</select>";
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
....
<input type="submit" value="Submit All">
</form>
```

edit_data.php

```
// create a mysqli connection called $db

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $tally=0;

    // build all queries for the batch
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $index=>$id){
        $queries[]="UPDATE `goh`.`sec1octa` SET `stu_status`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['status'][$index])."' WHERE `stu_no`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$id)."'";
    }

    // run all queries
    if(mysqli_multi_query($db,implode(';',$queries)){
        do{
            $tally+=mysqli_affected_rows($db);
        } while(mysqli_more_results($db) && mysqli_next_result($db));
    }

    // assess the outcome
    if($error_mess=mysqli_error($db)){
        echo "Syntax Error: $error_mess";
    }else{
        echo "$tally row",($tally!=1?"s":"")," updated";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Thank you , i try to make form by php but i can't , and also i use the code you write but i found syntax error and can't correct it , i'm sorry if bother you .

Comment: now it's work thank you , but can i make submit button to all ? not one by one , it's more easy i think , and what about select option any ideas ? because it's bad

Comment: but i ask in first to solve the problem about one update button to all field , and you make a solve one by one update filed so thank you but that's not what i ask first , it's clear . but thank you for your effort and flagged .

Comment: @MostafaMohamedGamal I have retracted my flag.  It is almost 1am and I must be getting cranky/tired.  I have done virtually all of the work for you, I hope you will award my answer the green tick and an upvote for being helpful.

Comment: i can't vote up ( under 15 rep. ) but thank you, and i will vote up when i reach 15 rep. ,

Comment: Ah, okay.  Let me know quickly if you have questions.  I need to sleep.

Comment: even i have go to sleep :) , i will try and thank you very very much .

Comment: it's work thank you very much . Good luck i wish i can help you someday